# Fortran 90 Basics: Newton's method; do loop doesnt seem to be doing, can anyone spot why?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

We were told to use x = -cos(((2i-1)/2n)π) as a starting guess for each loop of the newtons method (to find all of the roots) however i got the subroutine to print x immediately after first guess is made and it always seems to be -1 (So i think the problem is with the first guess); so i end up getting the same root for all my loops. I can't seem to think why this is happening at all and it's frustrating me so much.

```
subroutine Quadrature(n)

implicit none
integer, parameter :: dpr = selected_real_kind(15) !Double precision
real(dpr) :: ratio, P, dP, x, x_new, error, tolerance = 1.0E-8, Pi = 3.141592 !Define Variables
integer, intent(in) :: n
integer :: j

!Next, find n roots. Start with first guess then iterate until error is greater than some tolerance.

do j = 1,n

    x = -cos(((2.0*real(j)-1.0)/2.0*real(n))*Pi)

    print *, x

    error = 1

    do while (error > tolerance)

        x_new = x

        ratio = P(n,x)/dP(n,x)

        x = x - ratio

        error = abs(x_new-x)

    end do 

    print *, 'x =', x, 'P =', P(n,x), 'dP =', dP(n,x)

end do

end subroutine Quadrature
```

P(n,x) simply calculates the value of the legendre when n=n and x=x and dP(n,x) calculates it's derivative (so we can sub it into newtons method). Any ideas on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated i'm braindead over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at

```
x = -cos(((2.0*real(j)-1.0)/2.0*real(n))*Pi)
```

and think about your bracketing and Fortran operator precedence. Hint: Though you don't tell us I can tell the value of n you are using is a positive integer multiple of four.

A couple of other comments

1) Constants, like variables, also have a kind. Similarly expression like real(j) return default real. As you have written the above you are losing precision. Learn why the above line should be something like

```
x = -cos(((2.0_dpr*real(j,dpr)-1.0_dpr)/2.0_dpr*real(n,dpr))*Pi)
```

if you want to use "double precision" consistently through your code

2) Please in future supply a short but **complete** program that illustrates your problem. It really does make it much easier to work out what you are trying to do!

Comment: Thanks alot Ian, i have been wondering how to get integers into double precision and i've now seen what's wrong with the first guess. Sorry i didnt post a complete program i thought it'd be a bit long (but i guess it doesnt matter in one of those blocks)